# VPS Mailbox setup - Mailgun and Roundcube

Tags: email, mailgun, roundcube

Im running a VPS with NGINX and PHP 7.0 and I'm trying to setup Roundcube in combination with Mailgun.

I've setup a Mailgun account and got it all working (I can receive/send emails via Mailgun).

Now I'm trying to implement Roundcube as an email client, but I cannot seem to login with the Mailgun SMTP credentials.

I keep getting the following error message:

```
IMAP Error: Login failed for user@domain.com from IP1.IP1.IP1.IP1. 
Could not connect to IP2.IP2.IP2.IP2:587: 
Connection timed out in 
/var/www/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 184 
(POST /webmail/?_task=login?_task=login&_action=login)
```

Now I'm starting to doubt if this might even work, does anyone have experience with the following setup?

Answer (score 0):

Mailgun is not providing SMTP/IMAP to new users.
Maybe that's why.

Comment: They're providing SMTP, but not IMAP.